# Find a random time with an integer

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to generate a random number say 01:20 and then add 8 hours onto that and store that as a variable. However I want to do this within only the time and not use any random integers.

The date given for the query is found using a preset date at the moment set to 01-01-2017. StaffID is gotten from a loop through another table.

This is the PHP code snippet.

```
strtotime($random_hour = rand(00,23));
echo $random_hour . " Hour <br> ";
strtotime($random_min = rand(01,59));
echo $random_min . " Min <br> ";
$randomhourmin = $random_hour . ":" . $random_min;
echo $randomhourmin . "<br>";
```

This is the final SQL insert query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule (staffID, cdate, starttime, endtime, dayoff) VALUES ('$rowID','$fDate','$randomhourmin','$randomhourmin','0')";
```

Comment: `'$randomhourmin','0') <br>";` < why is there a `<br>` tag here? That should be throwing an error. Edit: stealthly removed in an edit.

Comment: Some of your variables are unknown.

Comment: Don't do your variable assignments within strtotime. Assign, *then* run them through strtotime -- preferably at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: I have explained the variables here. I simply am looking for a way to point towards a random time without a random integer.

Comment: you've an answer below; see that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for pointing that out, it hasn't created an error but I should have assigned it in the echo instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use below

```
$int= rand(1262055681,1262055681);
```

Also check mt_rand(), which is to have better randomness in the results:

```
$int= mt_rand(1262055681,1262055681);
```

To turn a timestamp into a string, you can use date(), ie:

```
$string = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$int);
```

Comment: yeah. Just use date("H:i:s",$int); to get only time.

Comment: When using this, I always get the same random number 03:01?